# read.table, ignore # and whitespace?

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to get many data files into R. The format of these files is in a 96-well plate (8 rows x 12 columns) and is(I believe) tab-delimited. In some cases, the value in the well starts with '# '. Whenever I try to read tables like this into R, I get an error. From what I've gathered from reading various articles, it's because I have '# ' in some of my rows. Here's an example of the data I'm trying to upload (this is one file).

```
<>  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  
A   # 101.23    93.691  89.311  90.181  70.267  60.658  # 2.6444    # 2.6685    # 2.6202    # 2.6846    # 2.6564    # 2.7048    
B   77.207  60.119  96.843  83.953  47.503  49.85   # 2.6524    # 2.6766    # 2.6524    # 2.6846    # 2.7128    # 2.6484    
C   56.673  68.737  89.283  78.68   41.88   46.453  # 2.6685    # 2.6806    # 2.6846    # 2.6726    # 2.6846    # 2.6726    
D   55.494  53.01   78.64   94.894  31.466  29.417  # 2.7329    # 2.6363    # 2.6363    # 2.7088    # 2.6806    # 2.6806    
E   40.113  42.451  # 105.39    87.033  # 16.504    # 17.297    # 2.6967    # 2.6967    # 2.7128    # 2.7007    # 2.6967    # 2.6927    
F   29.957  31.732  90.43   85.008  # 5.8405    # 5.9331    # 2.7007    # 2.7168    # 2.7048    # 2.6967    # 2.6927    # 2.7088    
G   # 14.962    # 14.62 # 2.6726    # 2.6726    # 2.6766    # 2.6806    # 2.7088    # 2.6685    # 2.6685    # 2.6605    # 2.6645    # 2.6283    
H   # 2.8819    # 2.8738    # 2.6846    # 2.7128    # 2.6444    # 2.6685    # 2.6564    # 2.7289    # 2.6887    # 2.6887    # 2.6887    # 2.6605
```

How would I go about reading data like this into R? It seems that whenever I try to use the function  "read.table", I get an error. I'm not sure how I can get R to simply ignore '# '. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The help page:?`read.table` should tell you how to change the comment character. These will be read as character values, so depending on you (unstated) vesion of R you may need to convenrt factor or character values to numeric (after removing the #'s).

Comment: I'm still confused by this; the help page doesn't seem to have clear instructions on this (or maybe I'm just not catching it clear enough). There is an option in read.table called `comment.char`, but when I put in `comment.char=""`, the # symbols in the text are still an issue. I think there is some issue with the fact that I have both "#" and " "(whitespace) together.

Comment: How in the world did your data wind up in such a format? Values are just whitespace delimited? No tabs or anything? This is really messy and it's going to be difficult to read because each tor is so irregular. It would be better to just remove all the "#" characters from the file first.

Comment: Haha, yes, I was afraid that maybe removing all the # characters was the only way to go, but I had my fingers crossed that maybe I wouldn't. The data is the output from Tecan Magellan software. I've put on the "extrapolate data" function, and anytime it extrapolates data, it adds "# " in front of the value.